# Filtering static content with Angular 2 without use of *ngFor

Tags: angular, filter

In the app I'm building, I have several cards that expand and collapse using Bootstrap's **Accordion**.

```
<div class="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Question?
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>

                      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="card-block">
                          <div class="row"><div class="col-3"><figure data-toggle="modal" data-target="#unidadeUm"><img src="./assets/img/unidade1.png" alt="A caixa de busca." width="230"><figcaption>Click to expand.</figcaption></figure></div><div class="col-9"><p>Answer.</p></div></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

I need to filter them, and in Angular 2, I naturally made an array with the answers and the questions (that are links used to expand/collapse the card).

```
<div class="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of items | search:'item,title':query">
                  <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            {{item.title}}
                      </a>
                    </h5>
                  </div>

                  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-block">
                      <div class="row"><div class="col-3"><figure data-toggle="modal" data-target="#unidadeUm"><img src="./assets/img/unidade1.png" alt="A caixa de busca." width="230"><figcaption>Click to expand.</figcaption></figure></div><div class="col-9"><p>{{item.desc}}</p></div></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Problem though**, the cards follow the same structure, besides the `ids` and `classes` (first card has `id="headingOne"` and `class="collapseOne"`, second has `id="headingTwo"` and `class="collapseTwo"` and so on and so forth)

I tried figuring my way out of this by creating another array object to replace the ids and classes, like

```
<div class="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of items | search:'item,title':query">
                  <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="{{item.head}}">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                      <a data-toggle="{{item.collap}}" data-parent=".accordion" href="#{{item.collap}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{item.collap}}">
                            {{item.title}}
                      </a>
                    </h5>
                  </div>

                  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-block">
                      <div class="row"><div class="col-3"><figure data-toggle="modal" data-target="#unidadeUm"><img src="./assets/img/unidade1.png" alt="A caixa de busca." width="230"><figcaption>Click to expand.</figcaption></figure></div><div class="col-9"><p>{{item.desc}}</p></div></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

... but it returns me this in the console:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'toggle' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
```

So, if I want my accordion working, I need to manually insert the content without an array, which makes filtered search impossible (in my knowledge). In this case, I think I have two options:

- Learn how to filter static content (without the need of an array for
  that)
- Or figure how to change ids and classes related to every object

Is there some way to do any of the two?

Thanks in advance.

---

### Edit:

I'm now using a fixed Bootstrap 4 for Angular 2 that can be found [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tree/master/src/accordion). It won't work as an array, so my problem with filtering static items remains at level zero. At least it's optimized now.

New working accordion code:

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="static-1">
              <ngb-panel id="static-1" title="Simple">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
                  aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                  sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                  craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
                  occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
                  labore sustainable VHS.
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
              <ngb-panel id="static-2" title="Title">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
                  aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                  sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                  craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
                  occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
                  labore sustainable VHS.
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
              <ngb-panel id="static-3" title="Title 2">
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
                  aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                  sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                  craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
                  occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
                  labore sustainable VHS.
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
            </ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: I've come to learn the existence of `ngClass`, in which I can alter the class of every array, but that solves only half of it.

Comment: the other piece I think you're looking for is `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;"` You then can use `i` in your `ngFor` as if it were a component variable that iterates with your items. If you'd like an example of building and ngFor with `<div id="item-one"></div> <div id="item-two"></div>` etc I can write up an answer for you. Also, a pipe may be the easiest and cleanest way to achieve your wanted result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it tomorrow and give feedbacks.

Comment: I tried creating it on my own but I screwed up somewhere. I tried starting with ngClass, which worked, but introducing `let i = index` confused me a lot, and I came to the point where I don't know how to replace `ids` and `classes` separately. Created a plunker to help visualize the part: https://embed.plnkr.co/3TC8ewbRPajkT3MdGeFC/ **Edit:** Yeah, I just realized I didn't use `i` anywhere after uploading the code. Will continue to try but I could use more assistance.

Comment: Also forgot to add console error generated by that plunker. _NgClass can only toggle CSS classes expressed as strings, got [object Object],[object Object]_

Comment: News; I found a repo @ github that fixes many Bootstrap 4 components for Angular 2, [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tree/master/src/accordion), so now I have a working accordion with arrays.